# How to sum minutes in array if their format is string?

Tags: java, time

I have an string array that includes some minutes like "00:05", "00:30", "00:25" etc. I want to sum the values as time format? Can anyone help me how do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total time in minutes:

```
int sum = 0;
final String[] mins = new String[] { "00:05", "00:30", "00:25" };
for (String str : mins) {
    String[] parts = str.split(":");
    sum += Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

You don't specify exactly how you want this output formatted.

If there may be hour elements as well, then replace the second line of the loop with this:

```
sum += (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) * 60) + Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll go for quick and dirty

1. [Split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) each String on the ":"
2. [Convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) both parts to integer
3. Multiply the first time by 60 to convert hours to minutes, and add the second part
4. Do this for each value in your array, and count them together
5. This results in the total time in minutes, which you can convert to whatever format you like

Answer (score 0):

this is my suggestion.  Neither compiled, ran, tested, nor guaranteed.

```
long seconds =  0; 
for ( String min : minutes )
{
    seconds += Integer.parseInt(min.substring(0,1))*60 + Integer.parseInt(min.substring(3,4));
}
return new Date ( seconds / 1000 ) ;
```

Comment: This line -- `new Date ( seconds ) ;` -- isn't going to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could [`substring`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) it, and then call [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) on the result.  For the hours part, do the same and multiply it by 60.

Answer (score 0):

Split the strings on ':', pars the values as ints and add 'em up.

Answer (score 0):

An object oriented approach:

```
public static TimeAcumm sum(final String[] times) {
    final TimeAcumm c = new TimeAcumm();
    for (final String time : times) {
        c.incrementFromFormattedString(time);
    }

    return c;
}

public class TimeAcumm {
    private int hours = 0;
    private int minutes = 0;
    private int seconds = 0;

    public int getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes() {
        return minutes;
    }

    public int getSeconds() {
        return seconds;
    }

    public void incrementFromFormattedString(final String time) {
        final String[] parts = time.split(":");
        this.minutes += Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        this.seconds += Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        validate();
    }

    private void validate() {
        if (this.minutes > 59) {
            this.hours++;
            this.minutes -= 60;
        }

        if (this.seconds > 59) {
            this.minutes++;
            this.seconds -= 60;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final String s = hours + "H:" + minutes + "M:" + seconds + "S";
        return s;
    }
}
```